# How can I concatenate multiline string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, append

There are lots of results for the correct syntax for appending `<li>`'s, however I am trying to find a solution where `+this['name']+` values are included in the `<li>`'s.  firebug is displaying `'SyntaxError: unterminated string literal'` and jslint is displaying `'Unclosed string'`. I've tried many different variations of the placements of the commas but I haven't been able to get it to work.

```
 $.each(data.result, function() {
     $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+this['name']+"</li>
                     <li>Age: "+this['age']+"</li>
                     <li>Company: "+this['company']+"</li>
                     <br />");
 });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

you can escape end of line with backslash character `\`, like so:

```
 $.each(data.result, function(){
 $("ul").append("<li>Name: " + this['name'] + "</li> \
     <li>Age: " + this['age'] + "</li> \
     <li>Company: "+this['company']+"</li> \
     <br />");
 });
```

This is due to the fact that Javascript automatically insert semi-columns sometime on line end. And in this case, you string weren't close. Another solution is to close each string on each line, and using `+` to concat them all.

```
 $.each(data.result, function(){
 $("ul").append("<li>Name: " + this['name'] + "</li>" +
     "<li>Age: " + this['age'] + "</li>" +
     "<li>Company: "+this['company']+"</li>" +
     "<br />");
 });
```

(Unrelated, but you `<br/>` aren't allowed inside a `<ul>` element)

Comment: Definitely go with the second solution proposed here

Comment: @Ian Yep, second solution is the one we see the most. Although, first solution work as well: http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings

Comment: You're right that the first solution works too, I'm not sure how well supported it is. I saw a question like this that had this same problem and I know someone proposed using `\` but it wasn't compatible everywhere (or something like that). Might as well go with the safe way

Comment: I think the second solution is slower

Answer (score 0):

This should be much faster

```
 li = '';
 $.each(data.result, function(){
     li += "<li>Name: " + this['name'] + "</li>" +
          "<li>Age: " + this['age'] + "</li>" +
          "<li>Company: "+this['company']+"</li>" +
          "<br />"; // could remove this and use css
 });

 $("ul").append(li);
```

See http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't want to concatenate this at all!  Consider for a moment what will happen to variable data that contains HTML or HTML-like data.  Using your method, it will be parsed as such, possibly breaking things and even opening you up to XSS attack methods.

You're already using jQuery, so the proper way is easy:

```
$('ul').append(
    $('<li/>').text('Name: ' + this.name), 
    $('<li/>').text('Age: ' + this.age),
    // etc.
);
```

(Note:  I believe `.append()` [allows as many parameters as you give it](http://api.jquery.com/append/).  If not, try using an array of elements as you append.)